# Alocação dinâmica, linguagem C

Tags: c

Estou fazendo alguns exercícios em C, e não estou achando onde ocorre o erro. Segue o enunciado: 6) Escreva um programa que aloque dinamicamente uma matriz de inteiros. As dimensões da matriz deverão ser lidas do usuário. Em seguida, escreva uma função que receba um valor e retorne 1, caso o valor esteja na matriz, ou retorne 0, no caso contrário.

No caso do meu código ele até funciona, mas às vezes só, por exemplo: se eu fizer uma matriz 3x3 e preenchê-la com valores de 1 a 9 e pedir para localizar o valor 6, o programa retorna que o valor não está na matriz, mesmo estando. Agora se eu digitar 8 para a busca, ele acha. Pelo que entendi são algumas posições que não retornam o valor da busca, porem, não consigo achar o ponto onde houve o erro para corrigir. Se puderem me explicar onde estou errando por favor.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int busca_linear(int m[], int l, int c, int b){
    for(int i = 0; i < l; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < c; j++){
            if(m[i * c * j] == b){
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

int main(){

    int linhas, colunas, *matriz, busca;
    printf("Digite a quantidade de linhas da matriz: ");
    scanf("%d", &linhas);
    printf("Digite a quantidade de colunas da matriz: ");
    scanf("%d", &colunas);

    matriz = (int *) malloc(linhas * colunas * sizeof(int));

    for(int i = 0; i < linhas; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < colunas; j++){
            printf("Posição [%d][%d]: ", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &matriz[i * colunas * j]);
        }
    }

    printf("Digite um valor para busca: ");
    scanf("%d", &busca);

    if(busca_linear(matriz, linhas, colunas, busca)){
        printf("O valor está contido na matriz.\n");
    }else{
        printf("O valor não está na matriz.\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

O enunciado diz para criar uma Matriz , mas você criou um Vetor , e na Hora de adicionar os valores e também na hora de fazer a pesquisa , você está usando o 'asterisco' "*" e então experimente usar o sinal de 'Adição' "+"  . . . !

```
scanf("%d", &matriz[i * colunas + j]); /// Adicao e Nao Multiplicacao
```

Comment: Realmente, era só o asterisco, está funcionando perfeitamente agora.

Comment: Estou estudando por um livro chamado Linguagem C: Completa e descomplicada,  de André Backes, e no livro diz que um dos modos de fazer a leitura de uma matriz com alocação dinâmica é justamente tratando ela como um vetor, Achei esse modo mais fácil se comparado aos outros que ele apresenta.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda